# Difference between consumption in static and dynamic mode for DRAM

Tags: memory, power-consumption

In all of datas about RAM, the consumption of this component is considered as equal to more or less 10 W. But I did'nt find if it's in static or in dynamic mode. I'm looking for the difference in consumption betwen this two modes. Maybe it's very low but it will be interesting to know how big is the difference.

Thank you for your responses

Comment: DRAM = Dynamic RAM

Comment: Ok you're right but do we know the consumption in static mode?

Comment: DRAM has no static mode - it is purely dynamic (i.e. Information is held in a tiny capacitator per bit) and will lose its data if not refreshed.

Comment: I disagree, because if there is no software running, you don't use the DRAM for calculation (I mean instead of the activate function of your laptop). And the DRAM is not made to save datas, it's just a temporary location for datas in order to calculate with processor so your right, you will lose the datas in case of no refreshing actions.

Comment: While there might not be access from software, there are still refresh cycles - so there is no real idle. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since DRAM does neither have a static mode nor a strict idle (refresh cycles still apply), the number you are searching for is the difference between idle and heavily loaded usage patterns. This seems to be quite significant, as an [InfoQ article](https://www.infoq.com/articles/power-consumption-servers) suggests:

[image: Power consumption comparison]

Comment: Thank you very much it's exactly what I'm looking for! Effectively you understood what I was looking for! I  don't know if the fact that it's a RDIMM instead of a DRAMM has a big influence on consumption.

Comment: RDIMMs will have a slightly higher power usage during access, but I don't suspect that to be significant.