# Estimation on power consumption for dram modules on desktop mainboard?

Tags: memory, power-supply, hardware-failure, ramdisk, dram

Desktop mainboard is equipped with Crucial, DDR4-2400, PC4-19200 2x16GB, CT2K16G4SFD824A, CL=17, dual Ranked, x8 based, unbuffered, non-ECC, 1.2V, 2048Meg x64bit modules. What is power consumption for idling 16GB (16Gbit x8 packages) dram module and for module at fulltime read/write/termination workload?

(Some numbers found before suggested 1.9 Watts for idling and up to 4.7 Watts for intense workload profile through module, but no overclocking or overvolting. Are these values reasonable?
Old numbers for DDR2 and DDR3, interesting, but year 2008 knowledge:
https://www.infoq.com/articles/power-consumption-servers)

Comment: Those values are reasonable on a per module basis - is 2 DIMMS =  twice the power. Note that I gave said reasonable - I don't know them to be correct for these specific modules.

Comment: Thx @davidgo  -  Mobile LPDDR4 numbers tend towards "1.1V 2y-nm 4.35Gb/s/pin 8Gb LPDDR4 mobile device"¹ and that is almost 40% below LPDDR3 parts at (probably) top power demand. [1] https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277919328_A_11V_2y-nm_435Gbspin_8Gb_LPDDR4_mobile_device_with_bandwidth_improvement_techniques

Comment: "Plenty of portable devices have required under 1W (watt) even over 12.8GB/s/ch data bandwidth to run the Ultra High Definition (UHD) displays. This requirement leads next generation low power DDR memory standard namely, LPDDR4. The conventional Pseudo-Open Drain (POD) has utilized VDDQ termination to operate over 1.6Gbps."² - means 64pins/ch - [2]_01/2014 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/293082372_Versatile_IO_circuit_schemes_for_LPDDR4_with_18mWGbpspin_power_efficiency

Comment: "Power efficiency is 2.4mW/Gbps/pin in 20nm mobile DRAM process, which is 44% lower value than that of LPDDR3."³ - [3]_01/2013 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261024968_A_Sub-10V_20nm_5Gbspin_post-LPDDR3_IO_interface_with_Low_Voltage-Swing_Terminated_Logic_and_adaptive_calibration_scheme_for_mobile_application

Comment: DRAM table for idle vs. performance power profile: https://superuser.com/a/1122236/981508